# Populate ObservableCollection with data from awaited Task.Run

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I am making Xamarin application and I have a problem with display data in my list view. So, basically I have web service from where I fetch data (that endpoint is non-async), so I don't want to block UI thread of my application, so I wrap the call to web service in `Task.Run` and await that task.

```
public class HomeDetailPageViewModel : ViewModelNavigatable
{
    public ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> cars;

    public ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> Cars
    {
        get { return this.cars; }
    }

    public HomeDetailPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        :base(navigationService)
    {
        this.cars = new ObservableCollection<CarViewModel>();
        AppearingCommand = new AsyncCommand(this.OnAppearingCommandExecuted);
    }

    public IAsyncCommand AppearingCommand { get; set; }


    public async Task OnAppearingCommandExecuted()
    {
        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
        {
            this.Cars.Clear();
            IEnumerable<Car> carsFromEndpoint = await Task.Run(() => CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                foreach (var carFromEndpoint in carsFromEndpoint.ToList())
                    this.Cars.Add(new CarViewModel
                    {
                        Manufacturer = carFromEndpoint.Code,
                        Model = carFromEndpoint.Name,
                        Price = carFromEndpoint.Price,
                        Year = carFromEndpoint.Year
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As I said CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context) is synchronous endpoint. If I use:

`Task.Run(() => CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context)).Result` or

```
CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context)
```

everything works as expected but that is not acceptable because it's block UI thread until Task is finished. I know it is not a good idea to use `Task.Run` to make fake asynchronous calls, but I don't see another way to keep app responsive, because I cannot change the endpoint of web service.

Thank you for the answer.
Cheers :)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know it is not a good idea to use Task.Run to make fake asynchronous calls

Using `Task.Run` to unblock a UI thread - even in a fake-asynchronous way - is fine.

> I cannot change the endpoint of web service.

This sentence doesn't make as much sense. All web services are asynchronous by nature. However, it's possible that your *client-side library* is strictly synchronous, in which case `Task.Run` is a fine way to unblock the UI while calling it. But you'll be working around a limitation in the client-side library, not the web service itself.

> I have a problem with display data in my list view.

Your problem is likely due to the `IEnumerable<T>`, not `Task.Run`. Here's some code I expect would work; the key is to move the `ToList` *inside* the `Task.Run` delegate:

```
public async Task OnAppearingCommandExecuted()
{
  using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
  {
    this.Cars.Clear();
    List<Car> carsFromEndpoint = await Task.Run(() => CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context).ToList());

    foreach (var carFromEndpoint in carsFromEndpoint)
      this.Cars.Add(new CarViewModel
      {
        Manufacturer = carFromEndpoint.Code,
        Model = carFromEndpoint.Name,
        Price = carFromEndpoint.Price,
        Year = carFromEndpoint.Year
      });
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is unnecessary if you remove the `ConfigureAwait(false)`; the `await` resumes on the UI thread for us. In fact, `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is a code smell.
- You probably don't want an asynchronous command here; you just want to [asynchronously load data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).

Comment: *BeginInvokeOnMainThread is unnecessary; the await resumes on the UI thread for us. In fact, BeginInvokeOnMainThread is a code smell.* with `ConfigureAwait(false)` it's not resumes on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Async commands in MVVM, the main problem is `NotSupportedException` while modifying the `ObservableCollection`. All the rest don't cause any issues if you're careful with concurrency.

Here's a class representing `ObservableCollection` for use from multiple threads which forwards all actions to `SynchronizationsContext` of the Thread where it was constructed.

Just use it instead of `ObservableCollection` *(not mine, grabbed from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516))*

```csharp
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public AsyncObservableCollection() : base() { }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) { }

    private void ExecuteOnSyncContext(Action action)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
            action();
        else
            _synchronizationContext.Send(_ => action(), null);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.InsertItem(index, item));
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.RemoveItem(index));
    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.SetItem(index, item));
    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex));
    protected override void ClearItems() => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.ClearItems());
}
```

And this `AsyncRelayCommand` class that I've made with help on StackOverflow ([Russian Community](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109137)). It doesn't freeze anything.

```csharp
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object param);
}

public class AsyncRelayCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null) 
        => (_execute, _canExecute, _context) = (execute, canExecute, SynchronizationContext.Current);

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        if (_context.Equals(SynchronizationContext.Current))
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            _context.Send(_ => CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(), null);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter));

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                await Task.Run(() => _execute(parameter));
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
}
```

Usage as with regular `RelayCommand` class from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

```csharp
private IAsyncCommand _myAsyncCommand;

// "lazy" instantiation with single instance
public IAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand => _myAsyncCommand ?? (_myAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(parameter =>
{

}));
```

```xaml
<Button Content="Click me!" Command="{Binding MyAsyncCommand}" />
```

`CommandParameter` is also supported.

With this you don't need pushing collecton change calls into UI Thread, use it as in usual sync code. And `Thread.Sleep()` or heavy job in the command will not freeze UI because it will run on a separate thread.

Usage with your code

```csharp
private IAsyncCommand _appearingCommand;
public AsyncObservableCollection<CarViewModel> cars; // are you sure that it must be public?

public HomeDetailPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        :base(navigationService)
{
    this.cars = new AsyncObservableCollection<CarViewModel>();
}

public AsyncObservableCollection<CarViewModel> Cars
{
    get => this.cars;
}

public IAsyncCommand AppearingCommand => _appearingCommand ?? (_appearingCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    // edit: fixed regarding to the accepted answer
    List<Car> carsFromEndpoint = CarEndpoint.GetAll(client.Context).ToList();
    foreach (var carFromEndpoint in carsFromEndpoint)
        this.Cars.Add(new CarViewModel
        {
            Manufacturer = carFromEndpoint.Code,
            Model = carFromEndpoint.Name,
            Price = carFromEndpoint.Price,
            Year = carFromEndpoint.Year
        });
}));
```